# Match 2 columns, but bring along all associated rows from the second column

Tags: excel-2010

What is the easiest way for Example1 to be converted to Example2 (I would be doing this with much longer lists)? Column C and D shall be associated to Col B for the output of Example2. This is not just to make Col B replicate Col A, although that is part of the solution. Thank you in advance!

Example1:

```
Col A  Col B  Col C  Col D
a      e       d       c
l      l       o       a
e      x       g       t 
x      a       s       s
```

Example2:

```
Col A Col B  Col C  Col D
a     a      s       s
l     l      o       a
e     e      d       c
x     x      g       t
```

Comment: Please elaborate on your logic.

Comment: As you can see, rows of C and D are still binded to Col B from Example1 after Col B matches Col A. Does this help?

Comment: Since column B is simply sorted alphabetically ascending, why can't you just sort all rows on B?

Comment: I don't see all letters ascending in order in Col B.

Comment: Please remember this aren't the list that I am working with - they are just examples of what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

It is not totally clear what you want to achieve and what the data qualities are, so a few assumptions:

- all items in Col A are also in Col B
- items in Col A are unique

Consider the following screenshot. Column A has been copied into column F. The formula in G1 is

```
=INDEX(B$1:B$4,MATCH($F1,$B$1:$B$4,0))
```

Copy the formula across to I1 and then copy G1 to I1 down.

If that does not do what you need, please edit your question, add a better data sample and more explanation.

[image]

Comment: This formula matches Col A to Col F, but does not bring along Column H and I, which are associated with Col C and D. Am I missing something here? Thank you for trying to help me out!

Comment: It's exactly what you show in your question. What is the problem? What do you want to see instead?

Comment: Did you just type in Col H and Col I? If so, that is not what I am asking. I need this to be automic to the change in the second column.

Comment: No, I used the formula. Read my answer. It says to copy the formula across and down.

Comment: I spelled out the copy thing.

Comment: Thanks. I need to learn how to read. I apologize for that. Thank you for your help! You have answered correctly.

Comment: Glad to help. Please mark the answer as explained in the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/)